# I need to return all the adIDs in the Adverts table that are NOT in TVRadio table

Tags: sql

I want to return the records with an adID NOT in the TVRadio station meaning only Web and Magazine. For context this is my - 
ER Diagram

[image]

This is my query so far,

```
SELECT Employees.employeeID, Employees.firstName, Employees.lastName, CampaignEmployees.campaignID
FROM Employees
LEFT JOIN CampaignEmployees
ON Employees.employeeID = CampaignEmployees.employeeID
LEFT JOIN Adverts
ON CampaignEmployees.campaignID = Adverts.campaignID
LEFT JOIN TVRadio
ON Adverts.adID = TVRadio.adID
```

This returns all the unfiltered data I need, my problem is that I can't seem to get the condition working. I've tried `WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT TVRadio.adID FROM TVRadio WHERE TVRadio.adID = Adverts.adID);` but it returns nothing.

Adverts and TVRadio tables - Image

[image]

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @C.Eog What is the relationship between the ADVERT table and the WEB, MAGAZINE & TVRADIO tables ? There doesn't seem to be one in your ERD.

Comment: Why has your TVRadio table no id? I also see your ERD is not correct and completed yet. "WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT TVRadio.adID FROM TVRadio WHERE TVRadio.adID = Adverts.adID)" TVRadio and Averts do not have adID!

Comment: My apologies, the ER diagram was drawn up a while ago, TVRadio, Web and Magazine all have their own adID

Comment: @C.Eog try adding the following WHERE clause WHERE Adverts.adID NOT IN (Select adID from TVRadio)

Comment: @Dugggie Unfortunately that returns 0 results (I've double checked the data)

Comment: @C.Eog OK, can you try running this query on its own, just to test --  SELECT adID from Adverts WHERE adID NOT IN (Select adID from TVRadio)

Comment: @Dugggie That returns all the adIDs NOT in TVRadio

Comment: @C.Eog OK good, now make a note of those results (the IDs) and run your original query again, but add Adverts.adID into the SELECT. Compare the 2 sets of results.

Comment: @Dugggie it seems to return all NULLs for the adIDs

Comment: @C.Eog, then you have a problem with your original query, let me take another look.

Comment: @C.Eog OK let's try to build this up a stage at a time. Can you try running this query and see if the results are correct ? (Note it's not a left join this time)    SELECT Employees.employeeID, Employees.firstName, Employees.lastName, CampaignEmployees.campaignID
FROM Employees JOIN CampaignEmployees ON Employees.employeeID = CampaignEmployees.employeeID

Comment: @C.Eog Also your 1:Many relationship in your ERD looks wrong between EmployeeCampaign and Campaign. Should this be the other way around ?

Comment: @Dugggie Yeah you're right, it should be the other way around

Comment: @C.Eog, OK, try running the query I posted a few mins ago.

Comment: @Dugggie That returns all the employees, if it's helpful I have a pastebin link with the SQL code for creating the database - https://pastebin.com/TrHZ3NVB

Comment: @C.Eog, yes just seen that. It looks like when you are inserting data, the campaignID in Campaigns is not matching the CampaignID in Adverts. Your CampaignIDs in Campaigns are 1,91,16,77,34 Your campaignIDs in Adverts are 25079332,63531211,15592835,99403438 etc, You seem to be inserting data in the wrong order in the Adverts table

Comment: @Dugggie I've just noticed that, that's a very silly mistake, sorry.

Comment: @C.Eog, Haha, we've all done that, or similar things at least. Sometimes it takes another pair of eyes to see it. Try correcting the data and see how your query works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like when you are inserting data, the campaignID in Campaigns is not matching the CampaignID in Adverts. Your CampaignIDs in Campaigns are 1,91,16,77,34 Your campaignIDs in Adverts are 25079332,63531211,15592835,99403438 etc, You seem to be inserting data in the wrong order in the Adverts table.

Once you correct the data, this query (which you were almost there with) will work.

```
SELECT Employees.employeeID, Employees.firstName, Employees.lastName, CampaignEmployees.campaignID
FROM Employees
JOIN CampaignEmployees ON Employees.employeeID = 
CampaignEmployees.employeeID
LEFT JOIN Adverts ON CampaignEmployees.campaignID = Adverts.campaignID
LEFT JOIN TVRadio ON Adverts.adID = TVRadio.adID
WHERE TVRadio.adID IS NULL
```

Comment: @C.Eog No worries.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are doing a `LEFT` join between `Adverts` and `TVRadio`, you need to add:

```
WHERE TVRadio.adID IS NULL
```

If `TVRadio.adID IS NULL` this means that `Adverts.adID` has not a matching `TVRadio.adID`
**Edit**:
You have a serious problem in the table `Adverts`.
You assigned wrong values to the column `campaignID` (I think they are the values of `clientID`):

```
CREATE TABLE Adverts (
adID INT(5),
campaignID INT(3),
clientID INT(3),
releaseDate DATE,
PRIMARY KEY (adID)
);

INSERT INTO Adverts 
VALUES (58224,25079332,1,'2019-08-12'),
(99534,63531211,91,'2019-04-20'),
(55755,15592835,16,'2019-09-08'),
(73418,99403438,77,'2019-05-30'),
(13463,79926376,34,'2019-06-26'),
(65660,47294923,1,'2019-07-19'),
(86926,43530233,91,'2019-10-10'),
(39925,14570146,16,'2019-12-15'),
(63452,90400859,77,'2019-02-28'),
(10124,63547321,34,'2019-08-24'),
(45537,25079332,1,'2019-03-11'),
(16232,15592835,91,'2019-04-30'),
(53040,79926376,16,'2019-01-02'),
(46791,43530233,77,'2019-09-24'),
(91974,90400859,34,'2019-04-16');
```

A fix would be to rearrange the columns like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Adverts (
adID INT(5),
clientID INT(3),
campaignID INT(3),
releaseDate DATE,
PRIMARY KEY (adID)
);
```

Comment: just tested it, doesn't seem to have any affect on what the query returns

Comment: If there are no nulls in your result at the `TVRadio.adID` column this means that all the `Adverts.adID` have a matching `TVRadio.adID` so there is no case of *adID NOT in the TVRadio*. Can you post sample data to clarify?

Comment: Yes of course, I've added an image of the Adverts table and the TVRadio table to the question.

Comment: Test this only: `SELECT Adverts.adID
FROM Employees
LEFT JOIN CampaignEmployees
ON Employees.employeeID = CampaignEmployees.employeeID
LEFT JOIN Adverts
ON CampaignEmployees.campaignID = Adverts.campaignID`. This will give you the Adverts.adID from all the joins. Is there among these ids any id that does not exist in TVRadio?

Comment: That returns a column of adIDs all of which are `NULL`, someone else suggested `SELECT adID from Adverts WHERE adID NOT IN (Select adID from TVRadio)` Without any of the joins this works and returns all the adIDs NOT in TVRadio

Comment: *all of which are NULL* this is strange. `SELECT adID from Adverts WHERE adID NOT IN (Select adID from TVRadio)` gives `all the adIDs NOT in TVRadio` right. But you need Employees not involved with radio ads right? Your problem is not reproducable without data. If you can post the data but in text form not images.

Comment: I have the SQL code for recreating the entire database. The client table will not have data because I entered that manually but it isn't needed anyway.

https://pastebin.com/TrHZ3NVB

Comment: There are 4 tables needed: Employees, CampaignEmployees, Adverts and TVRadio. If you can post the code for them.

Comment: @C.Eog What happened?

Comment: It was all because of that mistake, working now. Thankyou :)

Comment: And why did you accept a later answer? I posted your error several minutes earlier.